# Not able to print the entire content of text on thermal printer in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am printing a string of text on an 80mm thermal printer using textArea as the node. But after printing out, the height of the text is getting cut off. Below is the image of the output I am getting:

[image: Output from thermal printer]

But I am printing this sample text what is display on the receipt now:

```
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.appendText("*********************************************" + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("             " + companyName + "            \n");
    textArea.appendText("*********************************************" + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("Location: " + companyLocation + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("Contact Us: " + phoneNumber + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("TIN: " + tinNumber + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("Receipt No: " + transactionGeneratedId + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("Date: " + getCurrentTimeStamp() + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("---------------------------------------------" + "\n");
```

This is method for creating the string of text and appending to the textArea:

```
//*** issue print command
public void printReceipt(){
    // print(getPrintableText());
    printNode(getPrintableText());

}

//*** prepare text for printing
public Node getPrintableText(){

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    textArea.appendText("*********************************************" + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("             " + companyName + "            \n");
    textArea.appendText("*********************************************" + "\n");

    textArea.appendText("Location: " + companyLocation + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("Contact Us: " + phoneNumber + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("TIN: " + tinNumber + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("Receipt No: " + transactionGeneratedId + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("Date: " + getCurrentTimeStamp() + "\n");
    textArea.appendText("---------------------------------------------" + "\n");

    // get each product and add to printing list
    for(Products product: productList){

        if(product.getProduct_name().length() > 10){
            // getting the first 11 characters of the product name
            String name = product.getProduct_name().substring(0, 9)+ "...";
            textArea.appendText(product.getQuantity_purchased() + " x " + name +  "          " + currencySymbol + product.getUnit_selling_price() + "\n");

        }else{
            textArea.appendText(product.getQuantity_purchased() + " x " + product.getProduct_name()
                    +  "            " + currencySymbol + product.getUnit_selling_price() + "\n");
        }

        textArea.appendText("Subtotal                 "  + currencySymbol + (Double.parseDouble(product.getQuantity_purchased()) *
                Double.parseDouble(product.getUnit_selling_price())) + "\n");
        textArea.appendText("---------------------------------------------" + "\n");

    }

    // get overall total
    textArea.appendText("Overall Total             " + currencySymbol + totalPrice + "\n");

    String cashReceived = fieldCashReceived.getText().trim();

    // get total amount
    textArea.appendText("Amount Paid               " + currencySymbol + cashReceived + "\n");

    double balance = totalPrice - Double.parseDouble(cashReceived);

    textArea.appendText("_____________________________________________" + "\n");

    // get balance
    textArea.appendText("Balance                   " + currencySymbol + balance + "\n");

    textArea.appendText("*********************************************" + "\n");

    textArea.appendText("Thank you so much!" + "\n");

    textArea.appendText("*********************************************");

    return textArea;
}
```

And this is the print method:

```
    public void printNode(Node node) {

      Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();

      PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);

      Paper paper = PrintHelper.createPaper("Roll80", 80, 590, Units.MM);

      PageLayout pageLayout = printerJob.getPrinter().createPageLayout(paper, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 0, 0, 0, 0);

      double height = node.getLayoutBounds().getHeight();

      System.out.println("Height: " + height);

      double scale = 0.791;

      node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scale, scale));

      if (printerJob != null) {
          boolean success = printerJob.printPage(pageLayout, node);
          if (success) {
             printerJob.endJob();
             System.exit(0);
          }
      }

}
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: TextArea contains a scrollbar and may not display all of its text at once.  Consider creating a [TextFlow](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) and adding [Text](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) children to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this with a solution similar to @VGR's solution. I hope this might help someone who might be stuck with the same issue. I just construct the string with a StringBuilder class and set it to a label and return the label as a node in the end.

Check it here:

```
//*** prepare text for printing
 public Node getPrintableText(){

   Label text = new Label();

   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

   stringBuilder.append("*********************************************" + "\n");
   stringBuilder.append("             " + companyName + "            \n");
   stringBuilder.append("*********************************************" + "\n");

   stringBuilder.append("Location: " + companyLocation + "\n");
   stringBuilder.append("Contact Us: " + phoneNumber + "\n");
   stringBuilder.append("TIN: " + tinNumber + "\n");
   stringBuilder.append("Receipt No: " + transactionGeneratedId + "\n");
   stringBuilder.append("Date: " + getCurrentTimeStamp() + "\n");
   stringBuilder.append("---------------------------------------------" + "\n");

 // get each product and add to printing list
 for(Products product: productList){

    if(product.getProduct_name().length() > 10){
        // getting the first 11 characters of the product name
        String name = product.getProduct_name().substring(0, 9)+ "...";
        stringBuilder.append(product.getQuantity_purchased() + " x " + name +  "          " + currencySymbol + product.getUnit_selling_price() + "\n");

    }else{
        stringBuilder.append(product.getQuantity_purchased() + " x " + product.getProduct_name()
                +  "            " + currencySymbol + product.getUnit_selling_price() + "\n");
    }

    stringBuilder.append("Subtotal                 "  + currencySymbol + (Double.parseDouble(product.getQuantity_purchased()) *
            Double.parseDouble(product.getUnit_selling_price())) + "\n");
    stringBuilder.append("---------------------------------------------" + "\n");

 }

   // get overall total
   stringBuilder.append("Overall Total             " + currencySymbol + totalPrice + "\n");

   String cashReceived = fieldCashReceived.getText().trim();

   // get total amount
   stringBuilder.append("Amount Paid               " + currencySymbol + cashReceived + "\n");

   double balance = totalPrice - Double.parseDouble(cashReceived);

   stringBuilder.append("_____________________________________________" + "\n");

   // get balance
   stringBuilder.append("Balance                   " + currencySymbol + balance + "\n");

   stringBuilder.append("*********************************************" + "\n");

   stringBuilder.append("Thank you so much!" + "\n");

   stringBuilder.append("*******************************************");

   text.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

   return text;
}
```